# Ryu controller and manager WebUI app not showing the host and only listing switches

Tags: mininet, sdn, ryu

I have run the ryu_manager as:
ryu-manager --observe-links ryu.app.gui_topology.gui_topology --wsapi-host 0.0.0.0 --wsapi-port 8080

And mininet i am running as:
sudo mn --topo tree,depth=2,fanout=2 --switch ovsk --controller=remote,ip=127.0.0.1,port=6653 --mac

We can see the nodes and network topology is fine in the mininet console:

mininet> nodes
available nodes are:

c0 h1 h2 h3 h4 s1 s2 s3

mininet> net

h1 h1-eth0:s2-eth1

h2 h2-eth0:s2-eth2

h3 h3-eth0:s3-eth1

h4 h4-eth0:s3-eth2

s1 lo:  s1-eth1:s2-eth3 s1-eth2:s3-eth3

s2 lo:  s2-eth1:h1-eth0 s2-eth2:h2-eth0 s2-eth3:s1-eth1

s3 lo:  s3-eth1:h3-eth0 s3-eth2:h4-eth0 s3-eth3:s1-eth2

c0

But in ryu_manager web screen http://localhost:8080/ hosts are missing and only switches are listed.

is there anything missing here? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the RYU controller does not have the ability to display hosts in graphics or UI

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34555870)